# safely edit files with multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was using Threads in python and used to edit txt files by:

```
import threading    
lock = threading.Lock()

def function_that_will_be_used_for_multiple_threads():
    ###
    with lock:
        with open('file.txt','a') as filet:
            filet.write('something')
    ####
```

and it worked fine, but now I am using multiporocessing.Process and this method doesnt work so it is not safely to edit files now.

What might be an easy solution for this?

Comment: Did you look at [`multiprocessing.Lock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock)?

Comment: Or just traditional file-based locking -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock

Comment: That said, opening with type `'a'` -- `O_APPEND` -- _is_ in many cases concurrency-safe. For a POSIX-compliant filesystem, _all_ writes go to the end when a file is opened with that flag, even when the process performing the write doesn't correctly understand exactly where the end is. The big risk, then, is if your writes aren't atomic -- you want to be sure that one syscall == one unit-of-work, so you aren't potentially writing half a line and letting another process write more content at that halfway point, but that's something that careful development can generally ensure.